# More values in an if statement

Tags: javascript, html

I've made a small input loop where you can put in a word and when it's the correct value a check will be displayed.
When I tried adding more values something went wrong.
I added more values in diffrent ways but it didn't work.
Each time I put in a new value the input will display the check at any type of word or letter. Or it doesn't display anything at all.
This is what it looks like: http://prntscr.com/aux1d0 .
And here is the code with the values:

```
function check(id,value) { 
    if(value == "test") {
        id2=id.split("_");
        idcheck='check'+id2[1];
        idcross='cross'+id2[1];
        $("#"+idcheck).css("display","inline");
        $("#"+idcross).css("display","none"); 
    }
}
```

This is the code for the input loops:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var loopNoob = document.getElementById('1'); 
   var str = ''; 
   for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) { 
      str += '<form class="form-inline">\
      <div class="form-group">\
        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputAmount">Loopnoob</label>\
        <div class="input-group">\
          <div class="input-group-addon">'+i+'</div>\
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="focusedInput_'+i+'" onInput="check(this.id,this.value)">\
        </div>\
      </div>\
      <i style="display:none; color:red; font-size: 30px" class="display fa fa-times" id="cross'+i+'" aria-hidden="true"></i>\
      <i style="display:none; color:green; font-size: 30px" class="display fa fa-check" id="check'+i+'" aria-hidden="true"></i>\
    </form>'
 }
});
```

And at last the div code:

```
  <div class="container" id="1"></div>
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: where does your if close in your check function?

Comment: `I added more values in diffrent ways but it didn't work.` But you don't show us them. Why?

Comment: @Mike and the close of document ready is missing too. :(

Comment: @Mike There isn't any more code after the closing brackets, I just forgot to add the closing brackets in both the codes. My apologies.

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude This piece of code:  if(value == "test"). ? When I add more values with quotes or anything the input values will either not work or display the check when anything was typed in like so :http://prntscr.com/aux8wb . Even letters that weren't put in the value function.

Comment: And I ask again: how do you *add more values with quotes*?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I tried it like so: if(value == "test","cheese"). Or like this: if(value == "test, cheese").

Comment: The last one tests if value is equal to "test, cheese". This is true for "test, cheese" but obviously false for "test" or "cheese".You might want to go with if(value == "test" || value == "cheese"). For the future, before you assume that "first, second" works out of the blue, instead read a tutorial on the general topic.

Comment: @Aziuth Thank you for solving my problem.

Comment: You need to learn first some of coding, that's a basic programming skills (a conditional statement), that's not intrinsic related with javascript, but with basic development.

Answer (score 0):

```
function check(id,value) {
    id2 = id.split("_");
    idcheck = 'check' + id2[1];
    idcross = 'cross' + id2[1];
    if (value == "test") {

        $("#" + idcheck).css("display", "inline");
        $("#" + idcross).css("display", "none");
    }
    else {
        $("#" + idcheck).css("display", "none");
        $("#" + idcross).css("display", "inline");
    }
}
```

your check function has a little bit problem,change like this will be OK.